# good practice for python get number in this line

Tags: python

suppose I have string like this:

```
"any string here: 0.123"
```

I would like to know the pythonic way to extract the `0.123` and turns it into a number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to be "like this". Do you mean, it's a text and a number separated by a colon, or is it a string that ends with a number after a space, or is it a string that contains a number somewhere in it?

Comment: There is no one answer to your question, the context matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
 line = "any string here: 0.123"
 number = float(line.split(':')[1])
```

where we split `line` at the colon, then take the second half and pass it to the float function to obtain a float variable `number`.

Answer (score 1):

The provided answers are correct, but if you're looking for the most generic way to extract the first float from a string in Python, you could use regular expressions (the `re` module):

```
>>> import re
>>> float(re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)', "any string here: 0.123").group(0))
0.123
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say probably to split the string with the `:`:

```
str.split(':')[1].strip()
```